# deleteMany() in mongodb not deleting documents

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongodb-query

i have the following records in the collection ilists

> db.ilists.find()

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5efb10f25372d01d549954b1"), "name" : "hello user", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5efb10f25372d01d549954b2"), "name" : "click + to add items to the list", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5efb10f25372d01d549954b3"), "name" : "<---click the checkbox to deletet item in the list", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5efb170a32b1290c64950999"), "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5efb17790d9ff700204c43c2"), "__v" : 0 }
```

i have two empty documents and i am using deleteMany to delete them but i am getting the following

```
> db.ilists.deleteMany({"_id":"5efb170a32b1290c64950999"},{"_id":"5efb17790d9ff700204c43c2"})
{ "acknowledged" : true, "deletedCount" : 0 }
```

as you can see the deleted count is 0 and those documents are not being deleted any help for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteMany/), `deleteMany` expects filter query as the first argument. In your case, since the first argument does seem like a query, it's not working as expected.

You may try using the following:

```
db.ilists.remove( { _id : { $in: [
    ObjectId("5efb170a32b1290c64950999"), 
    ObjectId("5efb17790d9ff700204c43c2"), 
] } } );
```

Alternatively, if you plan to delete all the empty documents, you can update your `deleteMany` query as below:

```
db.ilists.deleteMany({ name: {$exists: false} })
```

Comment: Works for me! My doe was a bit differen, but basically the same:

    if (role === 'employer') {
            await Job.deleteMany({
                user: user,
                $exists: false
            })
      }